# JSON parse error on POST request

Tags: jquery, django, django-cors-headers

I used django-cors-headers, and config it.

Backend:
Django 1.11 + django-rest-framework 3.6.3

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.111:8000

Frontend:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "http://192.168.1.111:8000/api/user/forgot_password/",
        type: "post",
        data: {"email": "nikhil.29bagul@gmail.com"},
        headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
        success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"></div>

<button>Forget Password</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Getting 400 response for POST request and response content

```
{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}
```

But when I am calling this API from postman its work properly. How can I resolved this issue?

Answer (score 4):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.1.111:8000/api/user/forgot_password/",
    type: "POST",
    data:  JSON.stringify({ "email": "nikhil.29bagul@gmail.com" }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        $("#div1").html(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
});
```

try this one.

Answer (score 2):

You have bug in javascript, your Ajax POST request is formatted badly as you are not stringifying the data

```
data: JSON.stringify("{"email": "nikhil.29bagul@gmail.com"}")
```

Instead adding header manually you could use

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to convert your JSON to string before posting -

```
JSON.stringify({"email": "nikhil.29bagul@gmail.com"})
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Try to provide some detail in your answer e.g. why it isn't working and what they should try.